# What are the performance considerations of storing files in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm creating an application where users can edit their "files" for various purposes. Each user will have his / her own sandbox of files. The question is whether these files should actually exist on a drive or as long pieces of text in a MySQL DB?

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answered. How big are the files, what os, how many users, webinterface or not.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on my research, here's what I found...

Based on these two articles mainly (and other research):

> http://sietch.net/ViewNewsItem.aspx?NewsItemID=124
>
> http://blog.druva.com/2009/01/25/file-systems-vs-databases/

I think a DB would be better than a file system. The DB is optimized for fast reads and writes and is relational so lookups are QUICK. Space is cheap, so it growing fast isn't a HUGE concern.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime I face this problem it turns for me that storing files in filesystem ( or S3 ) is better solution. But for example Sharepoint stores all files in DB, so it depends on your project. You could also take a look at MongoDB, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: My issue is that I'll need REALLY FAST (realtime) writes and reads and history saving. So it's a lot of I/O a lot of times. Given that additional constraint, what say you?